# Images from HTML email not displayed

Tags: php, html, email

I have an HTML mail sender function (code given below). It works, but when I include an image in the email HTML, the receiving inbox sometimes doesn't display it. I've tested and tested, and the rule is simple: Yahoo display the images, Gmail and Outlook don't.

Before you say anything, this is not an issue with the receiving Gmail/Outlook user not allowing images to be displayed. I've allowed images in both, and they both display a blank space (the size of the image) where the image is supposed to be (or ALT text if I set it). It's as if they think the image URL is wrong, but it can't be wrong because Yahoo loads it correctly. Also, I've viewed the message source in Outlook and the image source is correct there.

Here is the mail-sending code, pretty straight-forward:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=$charset\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
$headers .= "From: $from_address\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from_address\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from_address\n";
ini_set("sendmail_from",$CONST_MAIL);
mail($to_address,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

And `$message` might be something like the following:

```
<a href="http://domain.com" target="_blank"> <img alt="" src="http://www.domain.com/correctimagepath/img.jpg" id="newsletter_01" style="border: 0px none;" height="470" width="670"></a>

<p>Hello world!</p>
```

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: `style="border: 0px none;"` is an invalid property, you probably want `style="border: none;"`. It might be that the HTML/CSS-parser is a bit picky about that?

Comment: the email clients are really picky on certain aspects when it comes to css. An error within the css will bork out on that ellement and wont show. Its not as lenient as a browser where you see what you did wrong, and give it an alteration, or where some rules are ignored when typed wrong. You have to do it correctly. As @ChristoferEliasson pointed out, you have a style error.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it. Now I have `style="border: none;"` but the problem persists.